# Разделение строки на отдельные числа (python-3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется файл с числами. В каждой строке по два числа, кол-во строк неизвестно. Я читаю каждую строку и добавляю её в массив:

```
data = []
with open('input.txt') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        map([int(line) for line in next(f1).split()], line)
        data.append(line)
```

Но при обращении к data[i] выдаётся оба числа. Я понимаю, что по логике, так и должно быть, но мне нужно получить каждое число по отдельности. Как это сделать?

Comment: Какой смысл в строчке ``map([int(line) for line in next(f1).split()], line)``?

Comment: В этой строчке кода считывается каждая последующая строка файла с учётом, что между числами есть пробел, и переводит каждую строку из string в integer.

Comment: Это вы описали то, что строчка делает. Вопрос де в том, для чего это нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужен плоский список

```
for line in f1:
    data.extend(int(i) for i in line.split())
```

Если двумерный

```
for line in f1:
    data.append([int(i) for i in line.split()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Разделить `data[i]` на два числа:

```
numbers = data[i].split() # если числа разделены пробелом. Если другим символом, то 
num1 = numbers[0]         # использовать его аргументом в split()
num2 = numbers[1]
```

Comment: Это мне и нужно, но по условию кол-во строк неизвестно.

Comment: Количество строк ни на что не влияет.

Comment: По вашему методу для каждой строки нужна переменная, но раз кол-во строк неизвестно, значит и кол-во переменных тоже.

Comment: какая еще переменная для каждой строчки?